# Uploading network image to firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I download an image file from network using a given url and upload it to fire store? 
I am having hard time downloading image from url and uploading it to fire store.

Comment: which lib u use for communication with server?

Answer (score 0):

you could do it for example like this:

```
upload() async {
   //pick image   use ImageSource.camera for accessing camera. 
   File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

   //alternative with ressource in your app:
   var src = // your image src
   File image = await Image.network(src);

   //basename() function will give you the filename
   String fileName = basename(image.path);

   //passing your path with the filename to Firebase Storage Reference
   StorageReference reference =
        FirebaseHelper.firebaseStorage().child("your_path/$fileName");

   //upload the file to Firebase Storage
   StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(image);

   //Snapshot of the uploading task
   StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
}
```

To get a better understanding of firebase storage and the upload process, and features like showing progress and more I recommend you checking this useful article too: https://medium.com/flutterpub/firebase-cloud-storage-and-flutter-fa2e91663b95